# Cross-origin XHR from a user script in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cross-domain, userscripts

Has anybody had any luck performing cross origin XHRs from a user script in Google Chrome? The requests go through to the server (I can see them in the logs) but, the `readystatechanged` event is never fired.

Extension permissions don't seem to be doing the trick. Neither is JSONP.

Comment: According to http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html if you wrap the userscript in an extension, the extension manifest can allow the userscript to make XSS XHR.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did read about this. The problem with this approach is I can't host it on userscripts.org and expect it to work straight away like other scripts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Current versions of Chrome (13.0.781 or later) now support most or all of the [`GM_xmlhttpRequest()`<sup>Doc</sup>](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) functionality -- **including cross-domain requests**.
See [Issue 18857: Support cross-site XMLHttpRequest in content scripts](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=18857#c124).

So this script works perfectly fine now on Chrome (and Firefox, of course):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            _Cross domain (XSS) GM_xmlhttpRequest, Chrome too
// @include         http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @grant           GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method:     "GET",
    url:        "http://www.google.com/",
    onload:     function (response) {
                    console.log (   response.status,
                                    response.responseText.substring (0, 80)
                                );
                }
} );
```

(Install that script, then browse any SO page.  The script will write the first 80 characters of the Google home page to the console.)

Comment: Thanks. I haven't looked at my userscript in ages, this definitely gives me a reason to make sure it is Chrome compatible.

Comment: Note that this only works for `@require` (just like above), [not for `@match`](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112746). The latter will throw `XMLHttpRequest cannot load [...] Origin chrome-extension://[...] is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Answer (score 5):

As of Chrome 13, you can do cross origin requests in Content Scripts if you included the permission to the website in the manifest.

<del>A user script in Chrome is a content script. Content scripts cannot make cross-origin XHRs. If you wish to do cross-origin XHRs, it should be done in the extension pages (background, popup, options).</del>

For more info:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html

Comment: This answer is now obsolete as of Chrome 13.0.781.