# Error when sending XHR from Chrome Extension to a PHP page: Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I want to send an XHR (using GET method) from a Chrome Extension to a PHP page.But when I try to run the code, I get an error:

```
    "Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP"
    "XMLHttpRequest Exception 101"
```

The PHP page loads fine when I call it directly in the browser, so being unable to locate the file would not cause the error. 
Due to these errors I am unable to send data from the extension to the PHP page to store in the database.I have included https://*/ in the manifest.json (under permissions ) of the extension, but it still does not work.

Please let me know how to overcome this error and send the request successfully.

PS: The page on which the extension is running and sending the XHR is a HTTPS page, while the PHP is a HTTP page.Could this be the cause of problem.If yes how to overcome this.

Comment: Where do you run this code, in a background page?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your doing this in a Content-Script, if so, then you cannot. It will be treated to the same origin policy. If you want to use XHR requests in a Chrome Extension, place it in your extension pages (Background page).

And when you do, make sure you add the the proper match patterns under permission:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html

For example, `https://*/` should be `https://*/*` and your XHR should be in a [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html) where your content script communicates with it through [messaging](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html).

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit old but just in case someone comes across this page. This is a replica of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936639/cross-origin-xhr-from-a-user-script-in-google-chrome).

You can make cross-origin-xhr from your content scripts if you have proper permissions declared.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot. XHR is subject to [the same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You could use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) instead though.

Comment: Hi Martin,Thanks for the response. I think it is possible for extensions to send cross origin XHR's unlike webpages. Source:http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html