# xmlhttprequest - exception 101 error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, userscripts

```
requrl_1 = "http://www.example.com/index.php";
requrl_2 = "http://www.example.com/redirect.php";
```

when I request "**requrl_1**", there is no problem. I'm getting response. "**index.php**" is not a redirector page.

but **requrl_2** is a redirector page, that is redirecting to another website(for example: http://www.cnn.com).

so when I request with `XMLHttpRequest`, I'm getting **exception 101** error.

I must request "**redirect.php**", there isn't another solution.

How can I do that? Why am I getting "**exception 101**" error.

---

I'm coding a **<strike>Greasemonkey</strike> userscript** script for **google chrome**.

Comment: Is this a synchronous request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to just install [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) and use it to run your script. Then you can code with [`GM_xmlhttpRequest()`<sup>Doc</sup>](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) -- which has cross-domain support.  And scripts get enhanced capabilities to match what Greasemonkey can do on Firefox.

**If you don't want to install Tampermonkey**, Chrome [userscripts now support cross-site requests via `GM_xmlhttpRequest()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936639/cross-origin-xhr-from-a-user-script-in-google-chrome/7452948#7452948).

So, you could use:

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method:     "GET",
    url:        "http://www.example.com/redirect.php",
    onload:     function (response) {
                    //-- Do your business here.
                }
} );
```

Comment: thanks but, I'm not writing script for myself, so all users who will use the script have to install tampermonkey.

Comment: They ***should*** install TamperMonkey anyway. ;)  **However**, Chrome has recently added cross-domain support.   See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the [XMLHttpRequest Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20070227/#dfn-send)

> If something goes wrong (infinite loop, network errors) the state must
>   be set to loaded and all members (excluding readyState) of the object
>   must be set to their initial value. Also, if async is set to false, a
>   NETWORK_ERR exception must be raised. In addition, all registered
>   event listeners must be removed.

Basically the redirect is causing the same origin policy to be fired. Which is firing the error. The request should be served with a proxy and not a redirect.