# Store and retrieve data online using a userscript

Tags: javascript, database, greasemonkey, userscripts

i want to be able to store and retrieve data online using a username and a password so a userscript that runs on a webpage can have personalized information.For example i want to write notes for users in a forum and want to retrieve them from any computer that my userscript is installed.

I thought google spreadsheets would do the trick but i havent been able to implement it.
I also have thought of using something like persistencejs https://github.com/zefhemel/persistencejs/blob/master/docs/sync.md or http://www.sencha.com/products/io/ but neither of them are simple enough for the knowledge on programming i have.

So is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Storing is trivial, reading is slightly more complex - but with help of [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), you can do it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no easy way to do this, you have to store data in your server and create a connection between your server and userscript.

here is how you can do that,

- create a login box in your userscript, so users can login.
- get **username** and **password** and send it your server page with [GM_xmlhttpRequest](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest).
  [chrome and firefox support cross domain xhr with GM_xmlhttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936639/cross-origin-xhr-from-a-user-script-in-google-chrome/7452948#7452948), so you will not have problem about that if you are writing that script for firefox or google chrome.
- in your server page get username and password and check them for matching in your database, than create json response that contains data for matched user.
- get response of request in your userscript and do what you want.