# Get current time from internet in google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, http, google-chrome-extension, httprequest

How can I get the current time (date) from the internet from my google chrome extension content script I'm writing? without using JQuery please! And I've Never dealt with http requests (or any server requests) so please include detailed code!
Thanks!

Comment: Little knowledge about JS and simple searches on the internet leads me to this: [JavaScript Date Methods](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp)

Comment: That takes the time from the local computer. I would like real time from the internet.

Comment: I see, you are right, maybe you can use an API or something?

Comment: I bet I can, but I couldn't get anything to work.. If someone could give me a piece of code that works, I'd be truly grateful.

Comment: If you don't want to deal with http request, how do you get internet time?

Comment: I don't want to deal with -JQuery-. I am well aware that this is easily manageable with a simple Http Request. I've -never dealt- with such requests, so please -include detailed code-. Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-origin XHR from a user script in Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936639/cross-origin-xhr-from-a-user-script-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 2):

### Updated

Considering there are [SOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restrictions when sending request from current web page, I'd suggest you sent ajax call in background page then using [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to transfer the data to content scripts. You could check [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) for more details.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "36716999",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ],
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "permissions": [
        "http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now"
    ]
}
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ query: "currentTime" }, function (response) {
    console.log(response.currentTime);
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.query === "currentTime") {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function () {
            sendResponse({currentTime: xhr.responseText});
        };
        xhr.open("GET", "http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now");
        xhr.send();

        return true;
    }
});
```

### Previous

You could make an ajax call to `http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now` to get the internet time, considering you don't want to deal with jQuery, which is very simple to make an ajax call, you could use native implementation, [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "36715494",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": [
                "content.js"
             ],
             "matches": [
                 "<all_urls>"
             ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
         "https://www.timeapi.org/utc/now",
         "http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now"
    ]
}
```

content.js

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
};

xhr.open("GET","https://www.timeapi.org/utc/now");
xhr.send();
```

Comment: @Xan, obviously I'm out of date again. Thanks for the catch, I will update later after I read related spec.

Comment: I'm saying this partly in jest, there's nothing inherently wrong with your code - but it looks much cleaner with `load` event instead.

Comment: @Xan, yes I know your meaning. I just can't believe I didn't know `onload` event for `XMLHttpRequest` before you commented out..

Comment: Just a little problem - at first it didn't work. I checked chrome's console and it said it block timeapi.org because "Your connection is not private". It allowed me to 'continue to the site anyway' and from then on it worked. But I don't really want my users to have to handle that error.   In permissions I have "<all_urls>" for now, so I think I got that covered. Any suggestions? Maybe some other time server?

Comment: @Nekoshet, I have updated my answer, to put it simple, sending http request from web page is limited by same origin policy, and I'm not sure there is https api for timeapi, which may affect you make ajax call in https page. A recommended way is to send ajax call in background page, then use Message Passing to transfer the data to content scripts, I have included sample code and reference link in the post, have a try.

Comment: Thanks. Ended up using the first solution but with a different site. Works great. Thanks a lot again.